# Post Error From Angular to Net Core HTTP 404

Tags: sql-server, angular, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm creating a fullstack web software and i'm using Angular,Net Core and Mssql...My web api is ready and if i use Postman,there is not any problem. I can list all products at my Bootstrap table on WebPage. But if send informations from Angular(angular form), it gives an error. **"The JSON value could not be converted to System.Int32"** It looks like type casting error. I changed validation rule from `categoryId: ["", Validators.required`] to `categoryId: [parseInt(""), Validators.required]` or `categoryId: [0, Validators.required]` My model variable type is number.I didnt understand. Thanks in advance...

My entire project at Github: https://github.com/SuperSayiyajin/FullStack_Workshop/tree/main/Northwind_Final

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

**This is my Net Core WebApi controller method:**

```
[HttpPost("add")]
public IActionResult Add(Product p)
{
    var result = _productService.Add(p);
    if (result.Success)
    {
        return Ok(result);
    }
    return BadRequest(result);
}
```

**This is my product-add module:**

```
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { ProductService } from './../../services/product.service';
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";

@Component({
    selector: 'app-product-add',
    templateUrl: './product-add.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./product-add.component.css']
})
export class ProductAddComponent implements OnInit {
    addProductForm: FormGroup;
    constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private productService: ProductService,
        private toastrService: ToastrService) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.createAddProductForm();
    }

    createAddProductForm() {
        this.addProductForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            productName: ["", Validators.required],
            categoryId: ["", Validators.required],
            unitsInStock: ["", Validators.required],
            unitPrice: ["", Validators.required],
        });
    }

    addProduct() {
        if (this.addProductForm.valid) {
            let product = Object.assign({}, this.addProductForm.value);
            this.productService.addProduct(product).subscribe(response => {
                console.log(response);
                this.toastrService.success(response.message, "Completed")
            }, responseError => {
                console.log(responseError.error);
                this.toastrService.error(responseError.error);
            });
        } else {
            this.toastrService.error("Product is not valid", "Error");
        }

        //console.log(product);
    }
}
```

**This is my product service.**

```
import { ResponseModel } from './../Models/responseModel';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { ListResponseModel } from '../Models/listResponseModel';
import { Product } from '../Models/product';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ProductService {
    apiURL = 'https://localhost:44324/api/';

    constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<ListResponseModel<Product>> {
        let newPath = this.apiURL + 'products/getall';
        return this.httpClient.get<ListResponseModel<Product>>(newPath);
    }

    getProductsByCategoryId(
        categoryId: number
    ): Observable<ListResponseModel<Product>> {
        let newPath =
            this.apiURL + 'products/getallbycategoryid?categoryId=' + categoryId;
        return this.httpClient.get<ListResponseModel<Product>>(newPath);
    }

    addProduct(product: Product): Observable<ResponseModel> {
        return this.httpClient.post<ResponseModel>(this.apiURL + "products/add", product);
    }
}
```

**This is product-add.html**

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h5 class="title">Add Product</h5>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <form [formGroup]="addProductForm">
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="Labels" for="productName">Product Name</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="col-9" type="text" id="productName" formControlName="productName"
                                class="form-control" placeholder="Product Name" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="Labels" for="categoryId">Product Category</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="categoryId" formControlName="categoryId" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Category Id" />
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="Labels" for="unitsInStock">Product Stock</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="unitsInStock" formControlName="unitsInStock" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Stock" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                        <label class="Labels" for="unitPrice">Product Price</label>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="text" id="unitPrice" formControlName="unitPrice" class="form-control"
                                placeholder="Price" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-fill btn-primary" (click)="addProduct()">Add Product</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Please post your payload of your HTTP request from the bottom of Network tab -> Headers subtab, and also the definition of the Product class in .net core

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.I added them to first message as a picture 4-5-6. It looks like angular send them as a string.

Comment: You can try clicking "View source" on the Request Payload and copy the JSON and paste it into Postman, and see whether you'll get the same error?

Comment: In case the pasted JSON doesn't work, the culprit might be string type posted from frontend. You can try to solve this by changing from type='text' to type='number' for corresponding input fields. You can also manually doing parseInt/parseFloat after you collect the form values and before sending the API

Comment: Yes it gives excat same error.Integers looks like string when angular send them to my api

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Icycool. It looks like i'm tired so much.Input type="number" is fixed the problem.

```
<div class="form-group">
       <input type="number" id="categoryId" formControlName="categoryId" class="form-control" placeholder="Category Id" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`categoryId` in product class is of type number, so yes you should use
`categoryId: [0, Validators.required]` or
`categoryId: [null, Validators.required]` and `<input type="number">`

And the reason why you did not get a **compilation error** is because all your Typescript code is **translating** to JavaScript and in JS we have no type checking like in typescript.
Please note that `this.form.value` is of type any, that's why typescript did not detect it as well.

Comment: They didnt work...


categoryId: [0, Validators.required],
categoryId: ["", Validators.required],
categoryId: [parsenInt(""), Validators.required],
categoryId: [null, Validators.required],

Comment: so the problem was with the input type, i edited my answer just to be full right answer.